# Reference request: a mathematical model of classical physics

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

Before entering the university I studied the book "University Physics with Modern Physics" (written by Young and Freedman). In that time I used to study physical problems with methods taught by that book.

Now I'm math student at a university and I'd like to study a mathematical model of Classical Physics and solve some physical problems using this model. For example: I would like a model in which I can formalize and prove that the electrical potential energy inside a hollow charged spherical condutor is constant and I also want to formalize and find, in this model, the [electrical field along the x-axis from a uniformly charged disk](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499914/field-of-a-uniformly-charged-disk-integration-question).

I'm only interested in models of **Classical Mechanics** (maybe using Symplectic or Poisson Geometry) and **Maxwell's electromagnetism**.

**My question is:** which book or article teaches a good mathematical model of Classical Physics? Please give some references.

The following PDF show more or less what I'm looking for: [Notes on Mathematical Physics for Mathematicians](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Etausk/texts/MathPhysics.pdf) (written by Daniel V. Tausk).

If you know one model, please, show how to formalize in this model one of the two examples I wrote before.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: To what extent does your own reference (to Tausk) not answer your goal?

Comment: @LSpice I liked that PDF, however I want more than one reference.

Comment: I wonder if professional physicists really refer to that book as being due to Freedman and Young. I may be showing my age, but I would have called it “Sears and Zemansky” since they are the original authors: look at the cover more carefully. Freedman and Young came on board since S & Z eventually died (1975 and 1981). I don’t know the publication history of their book that well, but it feels analogous to (not identical to, just analogous to) calling the Feynman Lectures “Leighton and Sands”.

Answer (score 5):

For a mathematically rigorous treatment of electrodynamics, see [The Mathematical Theory of Maxwell’s Equations](https://www.math.kit.edu/ianmip/lehre/sobraum2014s/media/main.pdf) by Kirsch and Hettlich.

For classical mechanics the "classic" reference is [V.I. Arnold's book.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Methods_of_Classical_Mechanics)